# RestSharp initialization of private properties

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm currently trying to initialize a private dictionary via a RestSharp call based on following json structure:

```
{  
   "id":1012,
   "name":"DataObject",
   "fileInformaton":{  
      "name": {
              "value:" "image.png"
      },
      "editable": {
              "value:" "no",
              ...
      },
   }
}
```

Thats the class:

```
    public class Dto
    {
           [JsonProperty]
           private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> FileInformation { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

           public string Name { get { return FileInformation["name"]["value"] } }
    }
```

But this case doesn't work. It only works if I set the dictionary to public with a private setter:

```
public class Dto
{
       [JsonProperty]
       public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> FileInformation { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
}
```

The reason why I don't set the dictionary to public is because I do not want to offer the whole keys just someone which I do via a public property.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and how is RestSharp relevant except the attribute? What you mean by "doesn't work"? Please explain

Comment: Why do you want it to be private?

Comment: Because I do not want to offer the whole dictionary just special key value pairs and therefore I created public properties which only returns those values!

Answer (score 1):

The jsonserializer will not serialize private properties / fields. You can solve this by implementing a custom `ContractResolver`, for the serializer. However i am unsure what the reason would be to have a property or field as declared as `private` in a DTO.

To clarify the problem this has nothing to do with the initialization itself, the dicationary gets initialized in both cases. But when declared as a private property it will be ignored by the jsonserializer.

Comment: Because I do not want to offer the whole dictionary just special key value pairs and therefore I created public properties which only returns those values!

But properties which have the attribute [JsonProperty] shouldn't be ignored by the jsonserializer.

Comment: I dont think I follow, so you don't want the dictionary to be serialized? You have other properties exposing certain keys from the dictionary? That you have excluded from your sample code?

Comment: So you have more properties in your class sort of like, `public string SomeProp { get { return FileInformation["keyname"] } }`?